# Why is NaN useful and in what situations

Tags: javascript, nan

Alright so I've been learning Javascript for 3 months and have gotten some pretty good exposure to solving several tasks. At the beginning of my book they have examples of NaN but they usually involve things like

```
NaN === NaN;        // false
Number.NaN === NaN; // false
isNaN(NaN);         // true
isNaN(Number.NaN);  // true
```

I've even looked on other stackoverflow posts and I still don't see a scenario of where I can use it in. That being said, in what situations does this global property help me? What are some practical situations in an actual program?

Comment: you could compare NaN to an sql `null`. "Unknown" value, or an error occured. It's poisonous, in that it will make anything else using the NaN value NaN itself, e.g. `var foo = 1 + NaN` gives you `NaN` as a result, not `1`. once an error occurs, you do not want to continue with that bad value, because your results become undefined at that point. and exactly like an sql null, you have to use special tools to detect it, e.g. `isNaN()` v.s. sql's `is null`.

Comment: `var helloWorld = 'hello world'; isNaN(helloWorld - 1)` simple one.

Comment: Usually when doing any type of arithmetic where you're using variables from an unknown source (user, database, api, etc..) it helps to check that the result you're getting is a number before moving onto more math that requires that value.

Comment: `var stringInput = "blah"; var convertedToNum = Number(stringInput); alert(isNaN(convertedToNum));`    (alerts "true", because "blah" couldn't be converted to a number)

Comment: It gives your program the notion of "maybe a number". You can do arithmetic without explicitly checking if your numbers are actually ones. Once `NaN` all subsequent calculations are omitted. So you can spare type checks but with the consequence that the result of your calc may be `NaN`.

Comment: @nnnnnn what does isNaN do in that case? Since we can't turn stringInput into number, convertedToNum is set to NaN, and since isNaN is true, we alert true?

Comment: Yep. If the original string was `"123.456"` it could be converted, so that would alert false. This is a pretty Mickey Mouse example, but still it is one way you can make use of `NaN`.

Comment: I guess `NaN` should indicate that Javascript developers are incapable of calculating :D Humor by Brendan Eich

Comment: P. S. Note that the [`isNaN()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) doesn't always do what you might expect - [MDN explains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NaN` is the number which results from math operations which make no sense:

```
Number('abc'); // NaN
0 / 0;         // NaN
Math.sqrt(-1); // NaN
Math.log(-1);  // NaN
Math.asin(2);  // NaN
```

When you do some math opertion and some operand is `NaN`, it will propagate to the result:

```
NaN + 2;          // NaN
NaN * 0;          // NaN
1 / NaN;          // NaN
Math.pow(NaN, 2); // NaN
```

Answer (score -1):

`NaN` is most useful when you have a value that's not a number (but ought to have been). You'll only get `NaN` back from the standard APIs in a few places, in particular [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

> The parseInt function converts its first argument to a string, parses it, and returns an integer or NaN.

Much of the value here is that once `NaN` has been introduced to a chain of math operators, the operations are defined (even if they wouldn't have made sense with the initial operands, thus producing `NaN`) and will continue returning `NaN`. Most of the math operators, as you can see from [the `/` instructions](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-applying-the-div-operator), have a clause to immediately return `NaN` if either operand is already not a number.

Comment: How exactly do you intend for something to be a number, but then it turns out not to be? Just wondering how that works.

Comment: As @Jack mentioned in the question comments, user input (or server input, or really any external source). `NaN` exists to keep a valid chain of operations when you receive invalid output. Rather than throwing because bad input accidentally made some op `x / 0`, you get `x / NaN` and a defined (if garbage) output.

Comment: @cresjoy `Math.sqrt(-1)` yields `NaN`, as do many other "invalid" mathematical operations that are intended to give numbers.

Comment: I see, so its more for just testing some cases and fixing some slip ups

Comment: It's better to get a value (`NaN`) which will happily continue through a complex formula (albeit end up with `NaN`) than a bad value that will throw halfway through your math. Garbage in/garbage out is better than garbage in/garbage truck catches fire/everything explodes.

Comment: @Niet Why doesn't `Math.sqrt(-1)` just throw like invalid code does?

Comment: By the way whats throwing? Is it like catching exceptions and such in java?

Comment: @LUH3417 What if you have an input `Math.sqrt(x)` and somebody enters `-1` into it? Then you get `NaN`, but your program will remain functional.

Comment: @cresjoy yes; to catch an exception, somebody had to throw it. ;)

Comment: Came at this looking for the word "practical". Should I keep this in my JS tool belt, tool box or tool truck? Thanks @ssube for calling that part out. It seems, for me, when I need it, I'll just borrow that tool from someone unlike myself who doesn't run screaming at the word "math".